# アクセントに関する質問：「韓国」ｖｓ「韓国人・韓国語」

Tags: pitch-accent

「韓国」はアクセントが頭に来ます。
「韓国人・韓国語」など、国の名称の後もう一文字が付く場合は全体的にフラットなアクセントになります。
それ以外にも例はありますが、そうなる理由がよく分かりません。
みんなそうやってるから私も従っていますが、説明しろと言われたら出来ません。
何か法則があるのでしょうか？
ではなく単純に発音しやすいからでしょうか？

＊最初は「英国」「米国」などを例として挙げていましたが、該当しない例であることをご指摘頂きましたので修正しました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

複合名詞でもアクセント核は一個だからだと思います。国の名称でなくても、例えば：

[ぶっきょう]{HLLLL} → [ぶっきょうと]{LHHHLL} / [ぶっきょうと]{HHHHLL} (仏教徒)

[まんぞく]{HLLL} → [まんぞくど]{LHHHL} / [まんぞくど]{HHHHL} (満足度)

[ちゅうがく]{HHLLL} → [ちゅうがくせい]{LLHHHLL} / [ちゅうがくせい]{HHHHHLL} (中学生)

後ろにつくのが一文字でなくても、前半は同じように変わります。例えば：

[かんさい]{HLLL} + [ほうめん]{LHHL} → [かんさいほうめん]{LHHHHLLL} / [かんさいほうめん]{HHHHHLLL} (関西方面)

[きょうと]{HHLL} + [だいがく]{LHHH} → [きょうとだいがく]{LLHHHLLL} / [きょうとだいがく]{HHHHHLLL} (京都大学)

[トイレ]{HLL} + [そうじ]{LHH} → [トイレそうじ]{LHHHLL} / [トイレそうじ]{HHHHLL} (トイレ掃除)

[スーツ]{HLL} + [ケース]{HLL} → [スーツケース]{LHHHLL}

---

このページが参考になるかもしれません：
http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/pmod/practical/02-07-01.php

Comment: 標準語では「ぶっきょうと{HHHHHL}」、「まんぞくど{LHHHL}」、「ちゅうがくせい{LHHHHLL}」、「かんさいほうめん{LHHHHLLL}」、「きょうとだいがく{LHHHHLLL}」はあまり聞かない気がします。というのは、二拍目が「ー」または「ン」である場合、ピッチは上がらないと思います。そして、二拍目がそういった音ではなく、なおかつ単独で発音された場合は、基本的に上がります。（「仏教徒」の例は後者のルールに当たります。）

Comment: ああ～確かに、どちらかと言えばそちらの方がよく使いますよね。