# もう for "already" and もう for "another"

Tags: grammar, definitions, pitch-accent

After studying the difference between もう and まだ (which seems clear to me now), I realize that there seems to be two different words spelled もう, which apparently have different pitch accents; high to low for the もう meaning "already", low to high for the (additive?)  もう meaning "another".

Are they actually different words and are those definitions correct? I don't seem to find much information concerning the pitch accents as well as the proper definitions in Japanese dictionaries (because my level is too low and Google Translate isn't accurate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

もう meaning "another" does have a low-high pitch accent and is used like this:

- もう【LH】3分
  another three minutes
- もう【LH】1回
  once more
- もう【LH】少し
  a little more
- もう【LH】片方
  the other one (of a pair)

もう meaning "another" is always followed by another word, and is pronounced like one compound (see [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56964/5010)).

Still, two monolingual dictionaries I checked explain those two types of もう under the same entry, so they're two different usages of the same word.

Comment: Thanks for your really great answer, I also particularly appreciate that you used examples in it! Are those monolingual dictionaries you speak of available online? Or would any monolingual Japanese dictionary be okay?

Comment: @Gyabu_7 One is デジタル大辞泉 available for free [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86/#jn-218382). The other is 明鏡国語辞典, whose online version is available [here](https://www.east-education.jp/products/dongri/meikyokokugo/) but it's not free. I suppose all monolingual dictionaries have similar definitions and examples, though.